# java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]

Tags: android, apache-commons

android studio 3.6

in build.gradle:

```
compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

api 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

in my code

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import java.io.*
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

     val file = File(folderPath + File.separator + resultFileName)
                FileUtils.writeStringToFile(
                    file,
                    fileContents,
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()
                )
```

but I get error:

```
 java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]
 java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forNameUEE(Charset.java:322)
    at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:534)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.write(IOUtils.java:810)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(FileUtils.java:1110)
    at com.myproject.client.common.util.AndroidFileUtil.saveTextToFile(AndroidFileUtil.kt:106)
    at com.myproject.client.service.RecognizedCheckDataService$Companion.saveRecognizedText(RecognizedCheckDataService.kt:117)
    at com.myproject.client.viewmodel.ScanCheckRompetrolViewModel.finishProcessRecognizedCheck(ScanCheckRompetrolViewModel.kt:1059)
    at com.myproject.client.viewmodel.ScanCheckRompetrolViewModel.access$finishProcessRecognizedCheck(ScanCheckRompetrolViewModel.kt:28)
    at com.myproject.client.viewmodel.ScanCheckRompetrolViewModel$runDetector$1.onSuccess(ScanCheckRompetrolViewModel.kt:193)
    at com.myproject.client.viewmodel.ScanCheckRompetrolViewModel$runDetector$1.onSuccess(ScanCheckRompetrolViewModel.kt:28)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]
```

Comment: otherwise you can use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Charset#toString()` is not well specified; on Android, it returns `"java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]"` as found [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7229). And that string is of course not the name of an existing charset.

But there is no need for the `toString()` call at all. The `writeStringToFile` method has an [overload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) that accepts a `Charset` directly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, replacing `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()` with `"UTF-8"` solved the problem.

<s>Note that `toString()` returns the result of `name()`, so replacing it with `name()`, as the comment on the question suggests, does not change anything.</s>
You can also use `name()` instead of an explicit canonical name as @johnnyb mentions in the comments below.

Comment: This is incorrect.  In older Android versions, name() and toString() return different values, but name() works fine.  Therefore, if you use name() it works on both older and newer versions.

Comment: Here's an old version where they are different:  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/tags/android-5.1.1_r38/luni/src/main/java/java/nio/charset/Charset.java#545 . Here is a new version where they are the same: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r46/ojluni/src/main/java/java/nio/charset/Charset.java#963